# What is an "Idea" in terms of time space and matter?

Tags: energy, space

If the physical world we know is made of matter stretched in time and space and some forces affecting it, what would be an Idea, pure Information or something similar.

Does those things don't exist in a physical model or did I just miss something.

If yes where to arrange it into the physical model? Is an idea just matter without time and Space?

Comment: This is a philosophical question, not a physics question.  Maybe there's also a Philosophy Stack Exchange?

Comment: At least there is a philosophy-tag in physics…

Comment: I don't think that tag should be there. As far as I'm concerned, any question tagged `[philosophy]` deserves serious consideration for being closed.

Comment: @eric I think this is indeed a physics question. Information needs to be present physically in the world, one way or another. Like the information in your computer is made of electrons bumbling around, and radio waves from radio broadcasts are a physical medium of information.

Comment: Does information realy _need_ to be present or can it be "there" _without_ representation?

Comment: @wrongusername: if we're going to discuss information, let's do it using the established field of information theory, and other related fields like statistical mechanics. Information theory doesn't deal with "ideas". It has strict technical definitions of what "information" means, how you calculate it, and what you can do with it. None of that seems to be involved in this question, which is part of why I say it's not a physics question.

Comment: @DavidZ: I tend to agree with you, with only one exception: "Representation Theory". All objects in Physics have a certain *representation* that ultimately grants us calculational power. If this discussion here will be about different ways to represent information, i think it should be allowed. Otherwise...

Comment: Every physical model consist of a set of ideas mutually related to each other. Or I don't understand the question.

Comment: If questions about "what is the material basis for phenomenon X" are ruled out-of-bounds because they are philosophical or metaphysical, then comments/answers like "Information must always be represented by the state of some physical system" should be out of bounds because they too are metaphysical (cannot be demonstrated on empirical grounds).

Comment: @Gerard: i don't think you understood the question: it's not asking how ideas play along in Physics, but rather what they are "made" of.

Comment: @LarsH: That's why i made a point, above, about "Representation Theory". Physics consists of the modeling of physical reality through a certain 'representation' of the phenomena at hand. In this sense, your criticism would not hold.

Comment: @Daniel (5 comments up): I agree that a discussion about the theoretical representations of physical objects could definitely be appropriate. But that's not what I see in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "idea" is something that happens in the confines of your *mind*: two particles colliding don't have ideas, they simply behave following the so-called "Laws of Physics", and so on.

In this sense, an idea, or, more generally, *creativity* itself, is something that only "exists" (if that's an appropriate term in this case) in your "mind", in this "emergent phenomena" driven by the inner working of your brain.

In this sense, i'd classify this question as a "neuroscience" one... ;-)

Comment: Besides an "idea in your mind" you could have an idea--the same idea, even--written on paper, or stored on a hard drive. So the same idea can have a whole bunch of utterly different physical manifestations.

Comment: So information, or knowledge is something that is only in our mind, but can be transferred with physical means to other minds.

So information is some kind of order that can be either perceived through senses or just be "there".

But what is it?

Comment: You may be interested in "information theory" which concerns encoding and communicating information; measures of the information content are, as you say, a kind of measure of order, or lack thereof. One starting point: http://cscs.umich.edu/~crshalizi/notabene/information-theory.html

Comment: Our minds are also physical.  Information is always physical.  See information theory, entropy.

Comment: Information it self is not physical but can have a physical representation.

Comment: @nibot - "Our minds are also physical. Information is always physical." The *brain* is physical. Beyond that, these are speculative pronouncements unsupported by empirical evidence. (If you disagree, specify empirical evidence for "information is always physical." "Everything is physical" is not empirical evidence but an a priori philosophical assumption.)

Comment: @LarsH: empirical evidence is when you observer or experience something. Observation and experience is physical, unless I am mistaken, so it could be hard to observe something that is not observable like "There is Information thats is not Physical" or "Information can not be non physical" == "Information is always physical".

Comment: @dStulle: exactly.

Answer (score 5):

Information must always be represented by the state of some physical system.  The idea in your head exists somewhere within the biological structures and electrochemical state of your brain, just as information in the computer is represented by the presence or absence of electric charge in the billions of bits of RAM.